# Bash programmation (Cygwin): Illegal Character ^M

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, bc

I have a problem with a character. I think it's a conversion problem between dos and unix.

I have a variable that is a float value.
When I print it with the echo command i get:

```
0.495959
```

But when I try to make an operation on that value with the bc command (I am not sure how to write the bc command).

```
echo $mean *1000 |bc
```

I get:

```
(standard_in) 1 : illegal character: ^M
```

I already use the dos2unix command on my .sh file.
I think it's because my variable have the ^M character (not printed with the echo command)

How can i eliminate this error?

Comment: How is `$mean` obtained?

Comment: Using ImageMagick "identify" command. But as I am on windows maybe it gives his result in a DOS format and not in Unix format. What causes a carriage character to be added.?

Comment: Okay, but what's the command you are running so `$mean` is populated? Something like `mean=\`identify ...\``... we need the complete line.

Comment: mean=`identify -colorspace gray -format %[fx:mean] $jpg_frame1`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't have Cygwin handy, but in regular Bash, you can use the `tr -d` command to strip out specified characters, and you can use the `$'...'` notation to specify weird characters in a command-line argument (it's like a normal single-quoted string, except that it supports C/Java/Perl/etc.-like escape sequences). So, this:

```
echo "$mean" * 1000 | tr -d $'\r' | bc
```

will strip out carriage-returns on the way from `echo` to `bc`.

You might actually want to run this:

```
mean=$(echo "$mean" | tr -d $'\r')
```

which will modify `$mean` to strip out any carriage-returns inside, and then you won't have to worry about it in later commands that use it.

(Though it's also worth taking a look at the code that sets `$mean` to begin with. How does `$mean` end up having a carriage-return in it, anyway? Maybe you can fix that.)

Comment: It's actually best practice to convert ANSI-C style string into integer, I think. Only solution that worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

This works:

> `${mean/^M/}`

You can get ^M by typing Ctrl-V followed by Ctrl-M. Or, alternatively:

> `${mean/$(printf "\r")/}`

The benefit of this method compared to **@ruakh**'s is that here you are using bash built-ins only. The first will be faster as the second will run inside a subshell.

If you just want to "unixize" $mean:

> `mean="${mean/^M/}"`

**Edit:** There's *yet another* way:

> `${mean/$'\r'/}`

Answer (score 2):

Running Windows stuff in cygwin has one nasty side-effect as you found out - capturing the output of Windows programs in a cygwin bash variable will also capture the CR output by the program.

Judicious use of d2u avoids the issue - for example,

```
runtime="`mediainfo --Inform='Video;%Duration%' ${movie} | d2u`"
```

(Without the d2u, ${runtime} would have a CR tacked on the end, which causes the problem you saw when you feed it to 'bc' for example.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should just save your script in UNIX format instead of DOS.

Comment: I already use the dos2unix command to convert it. Is it what you mean?

Comment: Yes, it is. I don't know why using dos2unix didn't solve your problem. The code looks good to me. I tried it and it works fine. But, if I save the script in dos mode, i get the same error: `(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M`. Usually i don't use dos2unix, just because I'm more comfortable with an editor. To replicate your code I used [pspad](http://www.pspad.com). Its free, maybe you could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo `echo $mean` *1000 |bc
```

If echo really isn't printing it, it should work.

Comment: That's a good thought, but it won't help. If `$mean` contains `^M`, and Bash recognizes `^M` as a word separator (which, by default, it does *not*), then `echo $mean * 1000` will already drop the `^M`, because `$mean` isn't quoted. If it *is* `echo` that's adding the `^M`, then it obviously won't work (as you've realized), and if the `^M` is in the variable and Bash *isn't* recognizing it as a word separator, then the inner `echo` will still print the `^M` and the outer `echo` will repeat it -- nothing gained.

Comment: @ruakh You're right, I hadn't thought it very through!

Answer (score 0):

`^M` is a [carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character that is used in Windows along with newline (`\n`) character to indicate next line. However, it is not how it is done in UNIX world, and so `bash` doesn't treat at as a special character and it breaks the syntax. What you need to do is to remove that character using one of many methods. [`dos2unix`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) tool can come handy, for example.

Comment: As I mentionned , I already used the dos2unix command on my .sh files.
Is it what yu mean or do I have to use in another way?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, this is a Windows line ending issue. There are many ways to fix the problem, but the question is why did this happen in the first place.

I can see this happening in several places:

- This is a WINDOWS environment variable that was set when Cygwin started up. Sometimes these variables get a CRLF on the end of them. You mentioned this was a particular issue with this one variable, but you didn't specify where it was set.
- You edited this file using a Windows ***text*** editor like *Notepad* or *Winpad*.

Never use a *text* editor to edit a *program*. Use a program editor. If you like VI, download [VIM](http://www.vim.org) which is available on Windows and comes on Cygwin (and all other Unix-based platforms). If VIM isn't for you, try the more graphically based [Notepad++](http://notepadplusplus.org). Both of these editors handle end of line issues, and can create scripts with Unix line endings in Windows or files with Windows line endings in Cygwin.

---

- If you use VIM, you can do the following to change line endings and to set them:

  - To see the line ending in the current file, type `:set ff?` while in command mode.
  - To set the line ending for Unix, type `:set ff=unix` while in command mode.
  - To set the line ending for Windows, type `:set ff=dos` while in command mode.
- If you use Notepad++

  - You can go into the *Edit-->EOL Conversion* menu item and see what your current line ending setting (it's the one not highlighted) and change it.
  - To have Notepad++ use Unix line endings as the default, go into the *Settings-->Preferences* menu item. In the Dialog box, select the *New Document/Default Directory* tab. In the *Format* section which is part of the *New Document* section, select the line ending you want. ***WARNING:*** Do not select `Mac` as an option. That doesn't even work on Macs. If you have a Mac, select `Unix`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. btw I was using Wordpad, and that probably causes the problem..